# Career Question: As a person who likes math is signal processing a career that's worth it?

Tags: algorithms, math

I like high level math and I love deep theory based math. 
In industry will I use high level math and theory to implement my own algorithms?
I love high level math but I do not love probability (applications) that much.
Will specializing in signal processing be a red flag?

How does the work of a day to day signal processing engineer in industry is like?

Comment: I'm not sure this is 100% the right forum for this. In any case, there's need for mentally flexible folks. You don't really say what kind of "high-level math" you mean – is it possible you might be not all that deep into math at this point? In any case, the way you phrased this, it's really a bit too opinionated to be answered definitely. So, I'd recommend asking a much more precise question that can be answered with signal processing knowledge instead of an opinion based on your *extremely* vague description.

Comment: I have taken Real Analysis and have taken Complex Analysis and many other math courses. I have not gotten deep in probability!

Comment: That, to me, sounds like you're an engineering student with the typical basic math courses (which tend to be superficial compared to the comparable courses for math students), not "deep mathematical theory". So, you're not doing anything special. Yes, you'll need that math if you'll be doing DSP in the future.

Comment: It's a big world where labels mean a lot to some and less so to others. Many people have careers where they do Signal Processing as a big part of their jobs but don't carry the label like Radio Astronomers for instance and the world changes, so programs get cut and the kind of work that you can make a living at changes. A big part of work, is working with others so interaction is important if you want to practice those skills.

Comment: DSP encompasses a lot of subfields and specialties.  A narrow subfield may limit career opportunities. For some jobs, you may also need additional interests and skills, such as low level coding/programming and software engineering.  Or hardware/logic design. Etc.

Comment: take a look at this http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=signal+processing&l=

Comment: Be known, the more managerial your career get, the better paid your salary become. Nobody in here will said that to you. But also you cannot escape your motivations, even if you want.